# Perl Module Cassandra::Lite Issue

Tags: perl, cassandra

While working with this module to add and remove rows in cassandra got following issue.
  It is ok if we add value to cassandra but when you try to remove it using

```
$cassandra_handle->delete( 'coumn_family', $key);
```

it just removes values for key but key is not removed. If key is not already present then it is added into it.

Why this is happening? Is it problem with the module itself?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with module I guess. You may try perlcassa.

> Although other Perl Cassandra clients exist such as Cassandra::Lite
>   and Net::Cassandra they have not been updated for many of the changes
>   in Cassandra releases >0.80 -[perlcassa](https://github.com/mkjellman/perlcassa)

I went through the source, there is a `remove` subroutine which you can use.

```
##########################################################################
# remove() lets you remove a key
#
##########################################################################
sub remove() {
    my ($self, %opts) = @_;

    eval {
        if (defined($self->{timeout})) {
            local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Remove timed out"; };
            my $alarm = alarm($self->{timeout});
            $self->_call("remove", %opts);
            alarm($alarm);
        } else {    
            $self->_call("remove", %opts);
        }

        close_conn();
    };

    if ($@) {
        my %error = %{$@};
        die("[ERROR] Remove was unsuccessful: $error{why}");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i tried installing that, but it depends on Thrift::XS and while installing Thrift::XS i am getting error as **C:\Perl\lib\CORE\perl.h(610) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys
/types.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\
VC\bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.** So Unable to work with it and p5-cassandra-simple.

Comment: Add the path to Environment Variable INCLUDE. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404141/nmake-cant-find-include-file-in-subfolder

Comment: Yes I also tried that and its giving following error when i nmake Thrift::Xs ** C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h(539) : fatal error C1189: #error :  You cannot use 32-bit time_t (_USE_32BIT_TIME_T) with _WIN64 **.

Comment: Also when commented the macro for time_t in crtdefs.h its showing error : ** C:\Perl\lib\CORE\dirent.h(30) : warning C4820: 'direct' : '3' bytes padding added after data member 'd_name'
C:\Perl\lib\CORE\dirent.h(40) : warning C4820: '_dir_struc' : '4' bytes padding added after data member 'dirstr'
c:\perl\lib\core\win32.h(77) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'windows.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2' **

Comment: Looks like a platform specific issue to me. Sorry I can't help with this. http://goo.gl/Z1PWtO